# $n a_n$ is bounded if $a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be such that $\sum_{n\geq 1} |a_n| <\infty$. Is it true that $\sup_{n \geq 1} |n a_n| < \infty$. If not can you provide one counter-example.

I know that if $a_n$ is decreasing then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n a_n =0$ and thus $n a_n$ is bounded. But I am not sure about a general sequence.

Comment: What does $\sum_{n\geq 1} |a_n| <\infty$ tell you about how big $|a_n|$ can get?

Comment: Consider the counterexample$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}&n=4^k\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @AlexanderGruber : at most as big as $\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$?